# requiredjs fall to load fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

When using requirejs, we do this:

```
require(['jquery','bootstrap','history','nanoscroller','noty','noty-theme','bootbox'],function(){
    //run code
}
```

But how can I know when requirejs fail to load any of the plugin and show an alert box with message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling prerequsites load failure in RequireJs require function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343188/handling-prerequsites-load-failure-in-requirejs-require-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching module loading errors and processing them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032517/catching-module-loading-errors-and-processing-them)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback function as the third parameter and that will be called if one of the dependencies fails to load.

```
require(['jquery','bootstrap','history','nanoscroller','noty','noty-theme','bootbox'], 
    function(){
        //run code
    },
    function (err) { // callback for dependency load failure
        alert(err);
    }
);
```

See [the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errors) for more details.

**Note** you can also use a global error handler.  The following is an excerpt from [the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errors):

To detect errors that are not caught by local errbacks, you can override requirejs.onError():

```
requirejs.onError = function (err) {
    console.log(err.requireType);
    if (err.requireType === 'timeout') {
        console.log('modules: ' + err.requireModules);
    }

    throw err;
};
```